# formatting negative currency amount in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, formatting, numbers, currency, nsnumberformatter

I have trouble formatting negative amounts. I have defined the following formatter :

```
NSNumberFormatter *nf = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[nf setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[nf setNegativeFormat:@"-¤#,##0.00"];
```

In an environment using an en_US locale, parsing the string @"-$244.32" returns a correct NSNumber object. However, parsing the string @"-€244.32" with a fr_FR locale returns nil.

Do you have any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Don't the French use comma for decimal place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be because fr_FR has the `,` as decimal separator, and not the `.` ?